# Droid Explorer cannot find device

Tags: droid-explorer

As the title implies, Droid Explorer cannot detect my Samsung Galaxy Tab A.
I've enabled USB debugging and set up Droid Explorer with Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.1.
I can detect the device with `adb devices` which shows:

```
5200dfccec4a940d    device
```

I can send commands to it as well, running `adb reboot` will cause the device to reboot, but Droid Explorer still cannot detect it.

[image: DroidExplorer]

Comment: Solution: https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

Droid Explorer is pretty old and unmaintained for years.

Some years ago Google changed the API of `adb`. If you are using a recent version of `adb` together with Droid Explorer which was developed for the old adb version this may end up in several non-functional features.

You should better check for an adb based tool that is still actively developed and maintained.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I'm just trying to view the root directory on my device. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just use adb on the command line. This works without problems: `adb shell` -> `cd /` -> `ls -l`